# Error 500 in new extensions instales (Joomla 3.0 Gantry Framework & Magnus tmpl)

Tags: joomla, components

On a page developed with Joomla 3.0, Gantry Framework & Magnus Template everything has been running fine but when installing new extensions like rs_mediagallery , facegallery or rokgallery , the installation finishs well but then when trying to access the component to configure (ie: Components --> Rsmediagallery) it shows a blank page and firebug indicates an error " 500 Internal Server Error".

All the site is running well including another extensions already installed.

tmp and extension directories have the correct permissions.

If someone has an idea in order to solve this error, I thanks

Campo

Comment: go to your global configuration and turn on error reporting. this will at least give you a start as to what the exact error is. your seeing the white blank page because the components/extensions are causing a php error so the scripts cant parse.

Comment: Please try asking your question at the dedicated [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) site :)